# Не сохраняется таблица в бд. HSQLDB

Tags: java, spring, jpa, dao, hsqldb

Изначально я написал проект с использованием `spring-jdbc` и бд HSQLDB не в `mem` режиме, сейчас решил переписать с использованием `jpa`. Когда использовал вариант с `spring-jdbc`  алгоритм работы был следующий:

1. Подключаюсь к существующей бд
2. Добавляю записи, вношу изменения в существующие записи

Сейчас с использованием `jpa` у меня таблица создается/удаляется при открытии/закрытии приложения. Почему такое поведение?
Вот код `entity`:

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "goods")
@NoArgsConstructor
@FieldDefaults(level = AccessLevel.PRIVATE)
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Product {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    long id;
    @Column
    String name;
    @Column
    String description;
    @Column
    LocalDate create_date;
    @Column
    long place_storage;
    @Column
    boolean reserved;
}
```

Так написан `DAO`:

```
public interface ProductDAO extends CrudRepository<Product, Long> {

}
```

Так написан `Service`:

```
@Service
public class ProductServiceImpl implements ProductService {

    private final ProductDAO productDAO;

    @Autowired
    public ProductServiceImpl(ProductDAO productDAO) {
        this.productDAO = productDAO;
    }

    @Override
    public Product findById(long id) {
        return productDAO.findById(id).orElseThrow(NotFoundException::new);
    }

    @Override
    public List<Product> getListProducts() {
        return (List)productDAO.findAll();
    }

    @Override
    public Product updateProduct(Product product) {
        return productDAO.save(product);
    }

    @Override
    public Product saveProduct(Product product) {
        return productDAO.save(product);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean deleteProduct(long id) {
        productDAO.deleteById(id);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Так подключаюсь к бд:

```
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCDriver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:hsqldb:hsql://localhost/goodsdb
spring.datasource.username=SA
```

Comment: попробуйте добавить `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update`

Comment: да, помогло, спасибо. Я уже проверил подключение к другим бд и все как надо работает, там автоматически выставляется параметр на `update`? Проверял на `postgre` и `mysql`

Comment: По умолчанию Спринг проставляет данное значение в зависимости от того, считает ли Спринг данную БД встроенной. https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-database-initialization.html